# Using Properties in spring config

Tags: java, spring

I have a property configuration depending on my environment, like this:

```
 <bean id="someConfigurer" 
       class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">  
        <list> 
            <value>classpath:properties/database.${my.env}.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:properties/morestuff.${my.env}.properties</value>
            [..]
        </list>  
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now I can keep different property files in my project, for example *database.prod.properties* or *database.qual.properties*. This works fine, if I start my application with -Dmy.env=foobar.

What happens if no environment is supplied? The application won't start, because of a FileNotFoundException thrown by the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. I don't want to keep a copy of all property files as a fallback. What I want is to set a environment as fallback, if the system property is not set.

I tried to solve this with a second PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer like:

```
<bean id="fallbackPropertyConfigurer"  
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">  
        <list>  
            <value>classpath:properties/default-env.properties</value>
        </list>  
    </property>
    <property name="order" value="0" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
</bean>
```

*default-env.properties* consists of just one property: `my.env=qual`.

The order is set to '0' to be sure, that this bean is evaluated first. I still get the following exception:

```
DEBUG  o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'my.env' in [systemProperties]
DEBUG  o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'my.env' in [systemEnvironment]
DEBUG  o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'my.env' in any property source. Returning [null]
DEBUG  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'someConfigurer'
INFO   o.s.b.f.c.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [properties/default-env.properties]
INFO   o.s.b.f.c.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [properties/database.${my.env}.properties]
INFO   o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@435a3a: defining beans [fallbackPropertyConfigurer,someConfigurer,[..],org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [properties/database.${my.env}.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
    [..]
```

If I comment out the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to get rid of the errors I can use `%{my.env}` in other beans.

Can anybody explain this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set your default value (in Spring 3) like this:

```
${my.env:qual}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to localize your build using the [Maven Assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) instead of fiddling with filenames in your Spring context.

Answer (score 0):

A longshoot try to add

> property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>

to your first bean as well

Answer (score 0):

as farmor said, the property 'ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders' should be set with true for the 1st bean too, as explained in API..

> Default is "false": An exception will be thrown if a placeholder fails
>   to resolve. Switch this flag to "true" in order to preserve the
>   placeholder String as-is in such a case, leaving it up to other
>   placeholder configurers to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use:

```
<property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
<property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
```