# Spring Batch: Job Properties

Tags: spring, spring-batch

How can i add property:

```
<property name="myProperty" value="value"/>
```

To the batch job definition:

```
<batch:job id="MyJob">
    <batch:description>description</batch:description>
    <batch:step id="step0">
        <batch:tasklet ref="MyJobCls"/>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="MyJobkListener"/>
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

then i can use this property in my run time.

Answer (score 2):

You can have the properties in an external file or inject it in PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer from xml:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location"><value>my_config.properties</value></property>
  <property name="properties">
   <props>
      <prop key="myProperty">value</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
</bean>
```

More details here: [Using Properties in spring config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241356/using-properties-in-spring-config)

Also if you run you process using CommandLineJobRunner you can set it from command line using -D ([How do I read JVM arguments in the Spring applicationContext.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598217/how-do-i-read-jvm-arguments-in-the-spring-applicationcontext-xml))
a-DmyProperty=value

For myProperty value in MyJobCls/MyJobkListener you have at leas to options:

annotations [How can I inject a property value into a Spring Bean which was configured using annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317687/how-can-i-inject-a-property-value-into-a-spring-bean-which-was-configured-using)

or inject from xml config:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/

Comment: thanks for your answer, im looking for adding properties for Spring Batch Job (not regular bean)  <batch:job id="MyJob">

Comment: so you want to have those params in the ChunkContext? (ChunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext())

Comment: can you describe how you plan to use the properties?

Comment: one of the plans is to have Job Type propert

Answer (score 0):

I am little confuse, What kind of property you are asking.
String or some kind or reference of spring managed beans.

If you want some string key-value pair then define it in the spring-batch-job parameter. it will be available to whole job with all the steps/.

If you want to have some property for reference/class, then add that property/class as member variable with setter and getter in your custom step or custom job class.
You can do the same for string property also.