# How do I set Spring Batch jobParameters in xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

This job.xml works great when using parameters.

```
<beans>
    <bean id="testFileItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
        <property name="resource" value="#{jobParameters['paramFileOuput']}"/>
        <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true" />

        <property name="lineAggregator">
                    ...
        </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

But what if I don't want to use job parameters but instead use Spring profiles...

```
<beans>
    <bean id="testFileItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
        <property name="resource" ref="testFileOutput"/>
        <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true" />

        <property name="lineAggregator">
                    ....
        </property>
  </bean>
  <beans profile="dev">
       <bean id="testFileOutput" class="java.lang.String">
           <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="file:c:/temp/testfile.txt" />
       </bean>
  </beans>
  <beans profile="prod">
       <bean id="testFileOutput" class="java.lang.String">
           <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="file:pathtoprod.txt" />
       </bean>
  </beans>
</beans>
```

This appears to work.  But this just doesn't feel right.  Is there a way to set the parameter in the xml using profiles?

Something along these lines (this obviously doesn't work)

```
<beans profile="dev">
    <setJobParameter key="testFileOuput" value="file:c:/temp/testfile.txt" />
</beans>
```

I can use any version of spring or springbatch.

Comment: You can try to move it into properties file. It might help you [Spring Batch: Job Properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209838/spring-batch-job-properties)

Comment: Yes...I could but overall I am trying to configure everything within the xml file itself.  (If that is possible)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
public FileOutput { 
private String filename; 
...
}
```

and

```
<beans profile="dev">
      <bean id="testFileOutput" class="FileOutput " c:filename="file:pathtoprod.txt">
</beans>
```

Unluckily, you cant use p/c namespace with java.lang.String, thats why you need a little helper class. Anyway, the solution would shrink your context.xml a few lines and looks more similar to your desired solution.